# MySQLi access denied from php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, joomla, access-denied

when i try to connect with MySQLi inside my PHP i get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in xxxxxxxx
>
> Connect Error (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

however i can login with the exact same credentials to phpmyadmin and using the mysql console.

i have granted the root@localhost all permissions.

here is my testfile that i use to connect to the database:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'rootPassword', 'myDatabase');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error );
}
echo 'Connection OK';
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

what should i do to fix this?

update:

here is the new code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ignis', '3307');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error );
}
echo 'Connection OK';
$mysqli->close();
```

with this i get the Connection OK, however when i try to connect like this using the 'joomla' way of connecting to the database i still get the error

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.

anyone has an idea of how to fix this?

here is the part of my configuration.php file which is used to connect to database:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
public $host = 'localhost:3307'; 
//tried using :59420 no success either but i have configured it
//to port 3307 in wamp so idk how the mysql console ever came up with port 59420.
public $user = 'root';
public $password = 'root';
public $db = 'ignis';
public $dbprefix = 'igns_';
```

result of `show processlist`

```
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| 85 | root | localhost:59420 | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure you only have one MYSQL Server running?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes only one server is running

Comment: exact same result: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` i have set the password for mysql to that and set the phpmyadmin password the axact same in the phpmyadmin/config.inc file

Comment: Just to check, try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 gives the same result

Comment: it gives the same error access denied with -p it doesn't

Comment: when i try that it also gives me access denied

Comment: that sounds like a bad idea because my database is packed with data

Comment: In well-built systems, root should have a password. It should NEVER be left blank for security reasons. If you're already logged in, try `show processlist` to make sure your host does say `localhost` and not something else.

Comment: You say _i have granted the root@localhost all permissions._ **This is not necessary** as `root` being the `SuperUser` can do anything to any part of the MYSQL Server without any modifications. If you actually did mess with `root` you may have done the damage yourself.

Comment: I Have granted those permissions after the error so this can't be the cause

Comment: @aynber show processlist shows id=85, user=root, host=localhost:59420, db=null (because i have not selected a database), and some irrelevant information

Comment: change password to `''`

Comment: @NewbeeDev doesn't work because i have specified a password for the root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a full day i have finally figured it out,

joomla was being weird about which file it used, it prefered the configurations.php.txt inside the joomla folder above the configurations.php in the site root.

why?

because in the factory.php file there is this piece of code:

```
public static function getConfig($file = null, $type = 'PHP', $namespace = '')
    {
        if (!self::$config)
        {
            if ($file === null)
            {
                $file = JPATH_CONFIGURATION . '/configuration.php.txt'; 
            }

            self::$config = self::createConfig($file, $type, $namespace);
        }
        return self::$config;
    }
```

where `JPATH_CONFIGURATION = JPATH_ROOT` (the joomla folder)
and `/configuration.php.txt` was hardcoded so it ignored the /configurations.php file.

but what i still don't get is why did the mysql suddenly break after a windows update? is it because there was a update that had something to do with blocking connections without specified ports? as this worked before the windows update.